# environnement remarque don't work with lualatex

Tags: luatex

Could you help me to solve my problem.
please look the MWE below

It's running ok with pdflatex compiler
You have to compile twice to have a good result

```
\documentclass{book}
% test_remarque.tex compile with pdflatex
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%% Note that this is font encoding (determines what kind of font is used), not input encoding. 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% compiler avec pdflatex
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[xcolor]{changebar} % pour barre verticale sur le côté
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}%pour insérer images et pdf entre autres
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\graphicspath{{images/}}%pour spécifier le chemin d'accès aux images
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% perfectionement Ã  faire gérer paramètrage variable si absent en auto je prends \linewith
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% --------------------- Environnement Remarque OK --------------------------------
\usepackage{minipage-marginpar}
% pour souligner une information particulière sour forme de remarque 
% Trait vertical sur le côté et pas de trait en haut et bas car trop laid
%usage avec entete : \begin{remarque} {\linewith}{}
% perfectionement à  faire gérer paramètrage variable si absent en auto je prends \linewith
\newenvironment{remarque}[2]%
{ \bigskip \cbcolor{red}
    \begin{changebar}
        \begin{minipage}{0.95#1 }
            \begin {wrapfigure}[2]{ l }{1.2 cm }
            \vspace { -7 mm }
            \includegraphics [ width=1 cm ]{remarque.png}%{/home/francis/Images/remarque.png}
            \end {wrapfigure}
            \textbf{Remarque: } 
        }
        {\par\bigskip\end{minipage}\end{changebar}} 
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    test de l'environnement remarque 
    
    \begin{remarque}{\linewidth}{}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{remarque}

\end{document}
```

[image]

but I have some error with lualatex compiler with the other latex file customized for lualatex (not enough !!!!)

```
\documentclass{book}
% % test_remarque_lua.tex compile with lualatex
%---------------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[xcolor]{changebar} % pour barre verticale sur le côté

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}%pour insérer images et pdf entre autres
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\graphicspath{{images/}}%pour spécifier le chemin d'accès aux images
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
\newenvironment{remarque}[2]%
{ \bigskip \cbcolor{red}
    \begin{changebar}
        \begin{minipage}{0.93#1 }
            
            \begin {wrapfigure}[2]{ l }{1.2 cm }
            \vspace { -7 mm }
%           \includegraphics [ width=1 cm ]{remarque.png}%{/home/francis/Images/remarque.png}
            \end {wrapfigure}
            \textbf{Remarque: } 
        }
        {\par\bigskip\end{minipage}\end{changebar}} % sans trait
 
\begin{document}
   \begin{remarque}{\linewidth}{}
      \lipsum[1-2]
   \end{remarque}
\end{document}
```

find below picture remarque.png[image]

Could propose me a solution Thank

Comment: changebar is not compatible with lualatex, you can use `\usepackage{luatex85}` to repair this, but changebar is meant for *change* bars, not for decoration frames and bars. Better use something like tcolorbox to define your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tcolorbox` based version:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\newtcolorbox{myremarque}{
enhanced,
boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{red},
colback=white,
sharp corners
}

\newcommand{\remarquestart}{\lettrine[findent=2pt]{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{remarque}}{ }\textbf{Remarque:}\quad}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{myremarque}
  \remarquestart
  \lipsum[4]
\end{myremarque}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: He I changed the name of png file   remarque.png

Comment: It's ok for me. Very good idea to use tcolobox. I changed the name of png file remarque.png